# How to give aliases to enum value?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Is there a way to give aliases to enum value ? example, I have this column called "status" in users table with enum data type that has values "0,1". The "0" value means the user is "Active" and the "1" value means the user is "Suspended".
I display the data in blade template like this

```
{{$user->status}}
```

The code above will return the real value which is "0" or "1". Is there away to make aliases like, if the status is "0" then the data will be displayed as "Active" instead of "0" ?

Comment: Accessores will help you, take a look [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways you can achieve this.

One, simple (but hard-coded way) to achieve this is to create a [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) on your Eloquent class, like so:

```
public function getStatus()
{
    $statuses = [
        0 => 'Active',
        1 => '....'
    ];


    return $statuses[$this->status];
}
```

`{{ $user->getStatus() }}`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Accessors](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) for this.

Add a method to your `User` model called `getStatusAttribute()`:

```
public function getStatusAttribute($status)
{
    return $status ? 'Suspended' : 'Active';
}
```

Or if your want to keep the original status attribute and create a new attribute you could do something like:

```
public function getStatusLabelAttribute()
{
    return $this->status ? 'Suspended' : 'Active';
}
```

This would be used as:

```
$user->status; //0 or 1
$user->status_label; //Active or Suspended
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can do on the User model:

Add the "active" attribute:

```
protected $appends = ["active"]
```

Then create a method for getting the attribute:

```
public function getActiveAttribute(){
    if($this->status) {
        return 'Active';
    }
    return 'Suspended';
}
```

Then on your view you can access to the attribute like this:

```
{{$user->active}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to do this:

```
{{$user->status === 0 ? 'Active' : 'not-active?'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary operator for this problem,
for example :

```
{{$user->status == 1 ? "Active" : "Suspended"}}
```